# WCF Duplex support for Mono 3.0.10

Tags: wcf, mono, duplex

Does any one know whether Wcf Duplex on tcp binding is supported in Mono 3.0.10.
I have written a simple test project that when running on the Mono CLR (windows version) throws a timeout exception at the first call to a contract method.

Any ideas?

### Update:

I have also tried to run that project on Mono CLR (version 3.0.12 installed on ubuntu),
and got the same timeout exception.

Any ideas?